# Time-Efficient Wide to Long Conversion Pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, bigdata

I have an dataset of around 54 million rows that I need to read from a tab-delimited text file, convert from wide to long format, and write to a new text file.  The data is too large to fit in memory, so I've been using iterators.  There are three separate variables that I want to move from wide to long, so I have been using three of them separate iterators

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

filename = "C:/example.txt"
iter_a = pd.read_table(filename, iterator=True, usecols=col_list_1, chunksize=100000)
iter_b = pd.read_table(filename, iterator=True, usecols=col_list_2, chunksize=100000)
iter_c = pd.read_table(filename, iterator=True, usecols=col_list_3, chunksize=100000)
```

Where all usecols lists contain a common identifier and otherwise distinct columns. Column names are based on year and attribute, so the column lists could look like:

```
col_list_1 = ['Key', 'A90', 'A91', 'A92']
col_list_2 = ['Key', 'B90', 'B91', 'B92']
col_list_3 = ['Key', 'C90', 'C91', 'C92']
```

And I want to change all the column names to just the years without the leading char/chars, and melt on the years only.

```
new_colnames = ['Key', '1990', '1991', '1992']
melt_values = ['1990', '1991', '1992']

for achunk, bchunk, cchunk in it.izip(iter_a, iter_b, iter_c):
    achunk.columns = new_colnames
    bchunk.columns = new_colnames
    cchunk.columns = new_colnames

    melted_a = pd.melt(achunk, id_vars='Key', value_vars=melt_values, var_name='Year', value_name='A').set_index(['Key', 'Year']).sort_index()
    melted_b = pd.melt(bchunk, id_vars='Key', value_vars=melt_values, var_name='Year', value_name='B').set_index(['Key', 'Year']).sort_index()
    melted_c = pd.melt(cchunk, id_vars='Key', value_vars=melt_values, var_name='Year', value_name='C').set_index(['Key', 'Year']).sort_index()

    join1 = melted_a.join(melted_b, how='outer')
    join2 = join1.join(melted_c, how='outer')
    join2.dropna(inplace=True, how='all')

    join2.to_csv('C:/output_example.txt', sep='\t')
```

While this does work, it takes an extremely long time.  I clocked one iteration with a 100,000 line chunk at 15 seconds.  Assuming it scales linearly, it seems that I'm looking at 2.25 hours runtime.  Is there any good way that I can speed this up? Maybe using either numpy arrays or multiprocessing?

Comment: Can we assume the input files all have the same keys and in the same order? (The chunked join wouldn't make much sense otherwise..) Also, you have `value_name='A'` three times, is this a typo? And is the data numerical? How are missing data represented?

Comment: @morningsun All input files do have the same keys and the same order.  Good catch on the `value_name='A'`, it was a typo.  The data is not necessarily all numerical.  A column will always have the same type, but different columns could be numerical or string.

Comment: Ah now I see you have 3 iterators *on the same file*, makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` csv parser is really fast, but you might try a pure python solution, because pandas is doing a bunch of things you don't really care about (type inference & conversion, all the join alignment, indexing, etc).

This is a just a start, but here's a very simple wide-to-long example.  You'll have to test it, but I'm guessing it may be faster than what you're doing above.

```
In [30]: %%file tmp.csv
    ...: Key,A90,A91,A92,B90,B91,B92
    ...: a,1,2,3,4,5,6
    ...: b,7,8,9,10,11,12

In [32]: with open('tmp.csv') as f, open('out.csv', 'w') as f2:
    ...:     f2.write('Key,Group,Year,Value\n')
    ...:     for i, line in enumerate(f):
    ...:         if i == 0:
    ...:             _, *headers = line.strip().split(',')
    ...:             headers = [(h[0], '19' + h[1:]) for h in headers]
    ...:         else:
    ...:             key, *rest = line.strip().split(',')
    ...:             for (group, year), value in zip(headers, rest):
    ...:                 f2.write(','.join([key, group, year, value]) + '\n')

In [33]: print(open('out.csv').read())
Key,Group,Year,Value
a,A,1990,1
a,A,1991,2
a,A,1992,3
a,B,1990,4
a,B,1991,5
a,B,1992,6
b,A,1990,7
b,A,1991,8
b,A,1992,9
b,B,1990,10
b,B,1991,11
b,B,1992,12
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using python 2.7, is there an easy workaround for the *headers unpacking?

Comment: Sure: `l = line.strip().split(',');   _, header = l[0], l[1:]`

Comment: I definitely like the idea of the pure python approach but I realize now that I wasn't clear enough about the output format that I was looking for, which is something more like what @root had, with each unique Group being captured in column rather than in row